# Java-Shifting Characters from Binary Files

Tags: java, file, methods

I looked at some previous threads about binary files and I am doing the dataStream like it says, but I am not for sure why mine isn't working as I think I am doing the same thing as threads say I am. My goal is to make a method that takes in a file name that is in .bin format with a shift integer. I will make a new file of the .bin type with the characters shifted. Only capital or lower case letters will be shifted though. I don't know the length of the binary file that is being read in and needs to go through all of the characters. The file will only have 1 line though. I have a method that gives me the number of characters on that line and a method that creates a file. The program I know does create the file correctly. Anyways, what is happening is it creates the file, then gives me an EOF exception about the line: char currentChar=data.readChar();

Here is my code:

```
private static void cipherShifter(String file, int shift) {
        String newFile=file+"_cipher";
        createFile(newFile);
        int numChar;
        try {
            FileInputStream stream=new FileInputStream(file);
            DataInputStream data=new DataInputStream(stream);

            FileOutputStream streamOut=new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            DataOutputStream dataOut=new DataOutputStream(streamOut);
            numChar=readAllInts(data);
            for (int i=0;i<numChar;++i) {
                char currentChar=data.readChar();
                if (((currentChar>='A')&&(currentChar<='Z'))||((currentChar>='a')&&(currentChar<='z'))) {
                    currentChar=currentChar+=shift;
                    dataOut.writeChar(currentChar);
                }
                else {
                    dataOut.writeChar(currentChar);
                }

            }
            data.close();
            dataOut.flush();
            dataOut.close();
        } catch(IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createFile(String fileName) {
        File file=new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            //Do nothing
        }

        else {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    private static int readAllInts(DataInputStream din) throws IOException {
        int count = 0; 
        while (true) { 
            try { 
                din.readInt(); ++count; 
            } catch (EOFException e) { 
                return count; 
            } 
        }
    }
```

So the error I do not think should be happening because I do have the correct data type and I am telling it to read just a character. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation says "Throws EOFException if this input stream reaches the end before reading two bytes." It sounds to me like you probably have an odd number of bytes in your binary file; when it hits the last one, it only gets half a character.

Comment: How does it get half a character? That doesn't even make any since, and also it shouldn't reach the end of the line because it is returning count once this occurs from the readAllInts method.

Comment: Again from the documentation, this time from DataInput.readChar(): "Reads two input bytes and returns a char value. Let a be the first byte read and b be the second byte. The value returned is:
 (char)((a << 8) | (b & 0xff))"

Comment: You might also want to watch out for your readAllInts method, since readInt() reads 4 bytes at a time. The returned value will be half as much as you probably want: since readChar() only reads two bytes at a  time, you'll only get through half the file with your for-loop.

Comment: So to fix me code completely maybe I should do the readAllInts method but multiply that return value by 2 or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really bushed and missed the obvious. I'll provide a more complete answer below.

Comment: Ok, and thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Note: If you don't wrap around, such as z+1 -> a, then the output won't be decipherable. Perhaps you missed a requirement.

Comment: Actually the requirement says it doesn't have to wrap around. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description above, your error is reported at the data.readChar() method invocation and not inside the readAllInts method.  I simulated the code near your error and got the same Exception on a text file at the same location.

I used the readByte method to read one byte at a time since you are mainly interested in ASCII bytes.  I also changed readAllInts to be readAllBytes so I work with total byte count.

```
private static void cipherShifter(String file, int shift) {
        String newFile=file+"_cipher";
        createFile(newFile);
        int numChar;
        try {
            FileInputStream stream=new FileInputStream(file);
            DataInputStream data=new DataInputStream(stream);

            FileOutputStream streamOut=new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            DataOutputStream dataOut=new DataOutputStream(streamOut);
            numBytes=readAllBytes(data);
            stream.close();
            data.close();
            stream=new FileInputStream(file);
            data=new DataInputStream(stream);
            for (int i=0;i<numBytes;++i) {
                byte currentByte=data.readByte();
                if (((currentByte>=65)&&(currentByte<=90))||((currentByte>=97)&&(currentByte<=122))) {
                    currentByte=currentByte+=shift; //need to ensure no overflow beyond a byte
                    dataOut.writeByte(currentByte);
                }
                else {
                    dataOut.writeByte(currentByte);
                }

            }
            data.close();
            dataOut.flush();
            dataOut.close();
        } catch(IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createFile(String fileName) {
        File file=new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            //Do nothing
        }

        else {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    private static int readAllBytes(DataInputStream din) throws IOException {
        int count = 0; 
        while (true) { 
            try { 
                din.readByte(); ++count; 
            } catch (EOFException e) { 
                return count; 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: So That piece of code I am already implementing as I close both stream and data. I am little confused because the loop should still work, not just without a loop. So can you update your answer with the entire cipher method? The answer does make since to me. As of the binary file, I simply take in a file that is .bin so maybe c.bin is my file. I then make a new .bin file and read the c.bin and go through the characters of the c.bin and then write those characters to the new .bin file.

Comment: See above and let me know if the exception disappears.

Comment: Your answer is extremely close, for some odd reason, it is making a new line in the .bin file that is created when the orginal file (file that is getting read) is only 1 line. I did have to *2 after the readallints method. I also noticed something I did not fix before up loading this and in the process of fixing, but I need to fix where I have newFile, it thinks c.bin_cipher when it should be ccipher.bin, but I can fix that. I don't know if that would cause the new line issue or not. Also, Bill mentioned that odd numbered bytes will be a problem, will it be a problem with this answer you gave?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the newFile string variable, that was my mistake for not noticing that. After I fixed that, the 2 line issue went away so your answered really does work provided I just put *2 at the numChar line. I am going to give you the check and thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't work with the odd case though so I will have to try to figure that out. Thanks again.

Comment: java char is 2 bytes so readChar will read two bytes at a time from the file.  And this means you will have an odd byte left over.  It looks like you need readByte and use byte instead of char and your logic should be if the byte value is >=65 && <=90 or >=97 && <=122, you want to shift it by adding a number to the byte.  Also, your shift value should not make the byte overflow.  Try changing the code that way.

Comment: I edited the code to read bytes and process bytes.  Try that.

Comment: Ok, that new code you gave actually fixed all the problems. This diffidently is making more since now. For the future when working with .bin file types, I have to remember to use readByte if I have any file with more than 2 bytes in it and use numbers on the ascii chart instead of saying less than or greater than a and z. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting the EOFException because you're passing the DataInputStream object to your readAllInts method, reading through the stream, then trying to read from it again inside your for loop. The problem there is that the pointer that keeps track of where you are in the stream is already near the end of the stream (or at the end of it) when readAllInts returns. I suspect it's *near* the end, rather than at it since the readChar() method is throwing the EOFException immediately, which it does when it only reads one of the two bytes it expects to be able to read before hitting the EOF.

To solve that problem, you could call data.mark() before passing the reader to the readAllInts method, then calling data.reset() after that method returns; that would repoint the pointer to the beginning of the stream. (This assumes data.markSupported() is true.)

You also have the problem we talked about above that your counter is reading in four bytes at a time, and your character reader is reading in two at a time. Your suggested method of doubling the return value of readAllInts would help (you could also use readChar() instead of readInt().)

You still need to think about how you're going to handle the case of binary files that are odd-numbered bytes long. There are a variety of ways you could handle that one. I'm too beat to write up a code sample tonight, but if you're still stuck tomorrow, add a comment and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Srikanth's answer above would also work for solving the reader-positioning problem.

Comment: So I tried the data.mark and it says it is not supported as I have to pass in an interger value. I passed in 0, I never used .mark before so what am I suspose to put in for the mark? I also tried the doubling with the readChar instead to the same original error.